# Are Synchronous Message Order and Total Message Order separate concepts?

Tags: distributed-systems, message-passing

I am currently studying [this book](http://www.cambridge.org/za/academic/subjects/engineering/communications-and-signal-processing/distributed-computing-principles-algorithms-and-systems?format=PB&isbn=9780521189842#eLvmzZRwK2h07LsT.97) on distributed systems. In the chapter on message ordering the authors appear to use the term *total message ordering* and *synchronous message ordering* interchangeably. It make sense why the authors may have done this. As far as I undertand a synchronous message-passing system enforces a total-order on all messages in the system.

Are they, in fact, one and the same concept? Or are these disparate concepts, and one of the properties just implies the other?